# Writing pretty print json output to fileoutput stream with GSON JsonWriter

Tags: java, json, gson

I am having hard time in writing pretty print json string on file using Gson library. Code I am using is here:

```
    Gson gs = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().create();     

    JsonWriter jsonWriter = null;
    try {
        jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stream, "UTF-8"));
        jsonWriter.beginArray();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (Feed feed : feeds) {
        gs.toJson(feed, Feed.class, jsonWriter);
    }       

    try {
        jsonWriter.endArray();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            jsonWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here stream is nothing but a file output stream. Even though I have enabled the pretty printing but still I am getting unformatted json string on file.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Using a JSONWriter ist redundant -- that's what GSON is for. Have you tried doing `gs.toJSON(feeds, outputStreamWriter)`?

Answer (score 10):

You can simply enable the pretty print by setting the indent.

```
jsonWriter.setIndent("  ");
```

Comment: ^ This is the correct answer. The `GsonBuilder.setPrettyPrinting()` call is ignored when using a `JsonWriter`.